# Alternative solution in Azure for CosmosDB with MongoDB API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to store documents each of around 8-10 MB in Cosmos DB with Mongo API. Since it exceeds the document size limit of Cosmos DB (not of MongoDB itself which is 16 MB) what would be the next best solution in Azure for me to store this queryable data ?

Comment: What kind of documents are we talking about? If it's actual documents, have a look at [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/). If you're talking documents with (non- / semi- / or ) structured data, have a look at [Data Lake Store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-store/)

Comment: what is the format of document?

Comment: JSON Document containing strings, number, array of string, array of array of string etc.

Comment: Then its better to go with azure blob storage

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Blob Storage from azure.it was very cheap and best for saving big size data.Your document can save in blob storage and you will get one url.
That url can store in you database table, instead of your whole 8Mb file.Whenever you required you can read the content from blob using that URL and your configuration keys.

Below I am sharing one link, to get better understanding.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-blob-storage-in-microsoft-azure-using-c-sharp-asp-net/

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Cosmos DB Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/attachments). You'll need to break apart that large JSON into what can become an attachment and what can't/shouldn't. You can then store those in Blob Storage.

> The attachment content is not indexed or searchable; the attachment resource properties are indexed and searchable.

Something tells me you have a bigger problem on your hands given the size of those properties.